# Add values to object from an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a problem to create an object list based from existing array.

Given I have an empty object:

```
let data = {}
```

which I would like to populate from an existing array:

```
const list = ['somedata1', 'somedata2', 'somedata3']
```

I want to make a following object list based from provided array:

```
data = {
  somedata1: undefined,
  somedata2: [],
  somedata3: 0
}
```

So I cant access either access or reassign them like so:

```
// Access
data.somedata1;

// Set new value
data.somedata2 = {subObject: true}
```

I've tried different approaches with `Object.assign`, `Object.fromEntries`, and this one which does not solve the problem:

```
list.forEach(i => {
  data[i] = undefined
})
```

And I expect to be the list such as:

```
data {
  somedata1: undefined,
  somedata2: undefined,
  somedata3: undefined
}
```

So I could reassign them like so:

```
data.somedata1 = 1100
data.somedata2 = ['somevalues']
data.somedata3 = false
```

**==== UPDATE ====**

So to make it work, I had to RETURN an assignment, instead of only ASSIGNING the object. I don't get it why it's like that, if someone could explain it will be perfect.

```
// WORKING: This function is return an assignment
list.forEach(item => data[item] = undefined)

// WORKING: This arrow function returns an assignment
list.forEach(item => {
  return data[item] = undefined
})

// NON-WORKING: This arrow function only assigns without RETURNing the value
list.forEach(item => {
  data[item] = undefined
})
```

Comment: Your `list.forEach` solution appears to work. Are you not getting the expected result?

Comment: What's wrong with your `list.forEach` approach, it works.

Comment: Yes i have tested with forEach it is working fine.

Comment: I get an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: key is not defined` when doing `list.forEach(k => {data[key] = ''})`

Comment: list.forEach(item=>data[item]=undefined)..This is only required.I don't know what is the problem then.

Comment: @aspirinemaga you are passing k and accessing key.That is the error i guess.

Comment: In your comment above you're referencing `key` instead of `k`

Comment: I get it! So to make it work, you have to RETURN an assignment. I update my POST

Comment: returning in a forEach statement does not mean anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert the values of an array to be the keys of another object (with their values as undefined, that you can do it in multiple ways):

here are two examples

```
const list = ['somedata1', 'somedata2', 'somedata3']

// imperative code
const data = {};
list.forEach(elm => {
    data[elm] = undefined;
})

// or

// functional code
const newData = list.reduce((acc, cur) => ({...acc, [cur] : undefined}), {})
```